# Create EXM campagin dynamically

Tags: exm

I am using sitecore 9.1.1 and I have created a custom newsletter template for EXM and I am able to create Email campaigns absed on this template now my requirement is that i have a data template and i have created item based on this data template which i am setting as data source for EXM Custom template.
Now i want that when ever someone is creating new Item based on that data template so simultaneously and automatically one EXM regular Campaign also be created dynamically.

Comment: Maybe an on ui item created event handler that checks the item template and creates the campaign

Comment: Hi Mark, I have implemented AddFromTemplateProcessor so when ever someone creates any item based on Article template I am able to do custom thing now I am searching to set this newly created item as data source Dynamically, Any idea?